# Java Core does not include Native memory section

Tags: java, out-of-memory, websphere

IBM WebSphere fail with "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError native memory exhausted", and generate javacore file. But this file does not include Native memory (NATIVEMEMINFO) section. Why?

IBM WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.39

```
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       ENVINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1CIJAVAVERSION JRE 1.6.0 Windows Server 2008 R2 amd64-64 build jvmwa6460sr12-20121024_126067 (pwa6460sr12-20121025_01(SR12))
1CIVMVERSION   VM build 20121024_126067
1CIJITVERSION  r9_20120914_26057
1CIGCVERSION   GC - 20120928_AA_CMPRSS
```

Summary, javacore dump contains only following sections:

```
0SECTION       TITLE subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       GPINFO subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       ENVINFO subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       LOCKS subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       THREADS subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       SHARED CLASSES subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       CLASSES subcomponent dump routine
0SECTION       Javadump End section
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please add some pieces of code and what you tried so we can help you

Comment: Which JVM you're using? It would be useful to know the output of "java -version"

Comment: Hi! Im tries interpreting java dump file, as discribe here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.win.71.doc/diag/tools/javadump_interpret.html

Comment: What happens if you trigger a Javacore manually, before the JVM crash? Does that contain a Native Memory section?

Comment: XSurgent, doesnt contain. I use following command:  
`set jvm [$AdminControl completeObjectName type=JVM,process=SERVER_NAME,*] 
$AdminControl invoke $jvm dumpThreads`

Comment: @unders10: That IBM Docs link states that some information can be missing depending upon the platform/OS and the nature of the triggering event. As the manually created Javacore doesn't have the Native Memory section, I think it's a restriction of the platform you're on (Windows Server 2008 R2).

Answer (score 1):

The version string shows you are running an earlier IBM Java 6.0 which used J9 VM2.4.

The NATIVEMEMINFO section was introduced in a later release of IBM Java 6 which used J9 VM2.6:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.doc.60_26/vm626/GenericWrapper/whatsnew_ga.html

The version you are using will not produce javacore files containing the NATIVEMEMINFO section.